# Small particle rotating around neutron star

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

First let me say I have read the article at "users.ictp.it › lns003 › Ruoff › Ruoff.ps.gz" about a small particles orbiting a neutron star and causing excitation of different modes of gravitational waves. However, the math is far to complicated to mean anything to anybody but experts specializing in the subject. I have made many searches about orbiting particles and relativistic effect without finding simple formulas, so maybe somebody can help.

To narrow my question, I imagine a purely theoretical situation where a point particle with rest mass $m_0$ orbits a stationary point mass $M$ in a perfect circle with $M$ at its center. I assume the peripheral velocity $v$ of the particle is constant and that the centripetal force balances the gravity pull, which is assumed proportional to the product of $M$ and the current mass of the particle and inversely proportional to the square of their distance $r$.

Now as long as $v$ is small compared to the speed of light everything is simple and gives $v^2= kM/r$, where $k$ is the gravitational constant as well as 
$v = \omega r$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity. When taking relativistic effects into account, I have the following simple questions as viewed by a stationary observer at the center:

1. Is a perfectly plane circular orbit possible?
2. Is the orbiting mass $m = m_0\gamma$?
3. Is the distance $r$ contracted or altered somehow?
4. Does $mv^2 = kmM/r$ still apply or is $k$ altered?
5. Is $\omega = v/r$ or is there some time dilation?
6. Is the angular momentum $mvr$?
7. Is the rotational energy half of m times v squared?

I realize that the questions and answers are probably intertwined but would nevertheless appreciate if somebody could write down the correct set of equations (hopefully without using the space-time warping caused by gravity) or point me to an article that does.

Comment: Irrelevant to answering your seven questions: the gravitational pull *is* the centripetal force, and if something balanced it out the particle would move in a straight line, not a circle.

Comment: Well, I would actually state that the particle undergoes _centripetal acceleration_ because the gravitational force is not balanced.  Centripetal is not a force...

Comment: Might be useful to include a proper link or at least a real citation to the paper you read, it might provide some extra background to users.

Comment: Probably my semantic is not precise but I think most people understand that I meant gravity pull = centripetal acceleration

Comment: I was referring to: Excitation of Neutron Star Oscillations by an Orbiting Particle
arxiv.org › gr-qc

Comment: By chance I found this in the forum: Time dilation effect on a particle orbiting at high speed something massive
 Nov 7, 2014
#1
Pro7ech.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Wikepedias article "Two-body problem in general relativity" adresses the subject in detail. Obviously things are very much more complicated than I imagened as it involves GR and Einsteins field equations to which there are no closed form general solutions. To sign off on the matter I have found the following supposedly correct answers to my 7 questions:

1. Is a perfectly plane circular orbit possible? YES but only stable in a unique set of circumstances.
2. Is the orbiting mass m=m0y? YES
3. Is the distance r contracted or altered somehow? NO.
4. Does mv2=kmM/r still apply or is k altered? NO it involves additional terms of higher orders of 1/r.
5. Is ω=v/r or is there some time dilation? YES and (seemingly) NO time dilation.
6. Is the angular momentum mvr? YES.
7. Is the rotational energy half of m times v squared? NO.
   The kinetic energy of m is m0(y-1)c2 according to Wikipedia.

Please correct me if I am wrong on one or more points.